# Null Pointer Exception while Changing the orientation of the screen android inside fragment

Tags: android, exception, pointers, null, fragment

I have a `ListView` inside a `Fragment` and i have enabled `onItemclick` on `ListView`. this configuration is working fine when the device is in  portrait mode but when when the configuration changes application crashes on item click.
to overcome this problem i set the property      `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">`
inside manifest file and set    `setRetainInstance(true);` inside `Fragment`.
now application do not crashes.
but the problem occurs again when i simply change the language of the device or do anything else which actually leads to recreate the activity.
application crashes with `NullPointerException`
Is there any way to handle recreation of activity without `NullPointerException` in android `Fragment`.

Comment: you must override `onSaveInstanceState`

Comment: Post you code which causes NPE.

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan, Can't see how it can help.

Comment: Using configChanges is only recommended when you have a good reason to prevent the Activity from being recreated on orientation change, and in your case you just need to find a bug in your code. setRetainInstance() also should only be used by Fragments which don't create Views.